# python scrapy code prints out the file I am reading from

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I have written some python code with scrapy to extract some addresses from a website.

The first part of the code is putting together the `start_urls` by reading the latitude and longitude coordinates from a separate file googlecoords.txt which then form part of the `start_urls`. (The googlecoords.txt file I prepared previously converts UK postcodes in google coordinates for googlemaps).

So, for example, the first item in the `start_url` list is "https://www.howdens.com/process/searchLocationsNear.php?lat=53.674434&lon=-1.4908923&distance=1000&units=MILES" where "lat=53.674434&lon=-1.4908923" have come from the googlecoors.txt file.

However, when I run the code it works perfectly except that it prints out the googlecoords.txt file first - which I don't need.

How do I stop this print happening? (Though I can live with it.)

```
import scrapy
import sys

from scrapy.http import FormRequest, Request
from Howdens.items import HowdensItem

class howdensSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "howdens"
    allowed_domains = ["www.howdens.com"]

    # read the file that has a list of google coordinates that are converted from postcodes
    with open("googlecoords.txt") as f:
        googlecoords = [x.strip('\n') for x in f.readlines()]

    # from the goole coordinates build the start URLs
    start_urls = []
    for a in range(len(googlecoords)):
        start_urls.append("https://www.howdens.com/process/searchLocationsNear.php?{}&distance=1000&units=MILES".format(googlecoords[a]))

    # cycle through 6 of the first relevant items returned in the text
    def parse(self, response):
        for sel in response.xpath('/html/body'):
            for i in range(0,6):
                try:
                    item = HowdensItem()
                    item['name'] =sel.xpath('.//text()').re(r'(?<="name":")(.*?)(?=","street")')[i]
                    item['street'] =sel.xpath('.//text()').re(r'(?<="street":")(.*?)(?=","town")')[i]
                    item['town'] = sel.xpath('.//text()').re(r'(?<="town":")(.*?)(?=","pc")')[i]
                    item['pc'] = sel.xpath('.//text()').re(r'(?<="pc":")(.*?)(?=","state")')[i]
                    yield item
                except IndexError:
                    pass
```

Comment: The data is json... use a json parser to work with it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like someone in the comments pointed out you should load it up with `json` module in `start_requests()` method:

```
import scrapy
import json

class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    start_urls = ['https://www.howdens.com/process/searchLocationsNear.php?lat=53.674434&lon=-1.4908923&distance=1000&units=MILES']

    def parse(self, response):
        data = json.loads(response.body_as_unicode())
        items = data['response']['depots'] 
        for item in items:
            url_template = "https://www.howdens.com/process/searchLocationsNear.php?{}&distance=1000&units=MILES"
            url = url_template.format(item['lat'])  # format in your location here
            yield scrapy.Request(url, self.parse_item)

    def parse_item(self, response): 
        print(response.url)
```